# how to Scroll(horizontally) in collection view on button press?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with images.I want to perform scrolling on button press . i have searched on google I found out only to set contentoffset but I want to scroll with animations(scroll should bounce if content is past the scrolling area).I have added a [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtiCf.png) to show you what exactly i have to do, in picture there is a collection view and little arrows on both sides are buttons.

```
 @IBAction func moveScrollLeft(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.imageCollectionView.contentOffset.x -= 50
        }, completion: nil)
    print(imageCollectionView.contentOffset.x)
}

@IBAction func moveScrollRight(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.imageCollectionView.contentOffset.x += 50
        }, completion: nil)
    print(imageCollectionView.contentOffset.x)

}
```

Comment: UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView. You can use collectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated:true). About the bounces, you'll have to check that contentOffset.x + bounds.width > contentSize.width and animate the bounce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UICollectionview's `scrollToItemAtIndexPath(_:atScrollPosition:animated:)`
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

For example:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 0)
imageCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code i have modify your code:

```
@IBAction func moveScrollLeft(sender: UIButton) {

        self.imageCollectionView.contentOffset.x -= 50

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        }, completion: nil)
             self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    print(imageCollectionView.contentOffset.x)
}

@IBAction func moveScrollRight(sender: UIButton) {

        self.imageCollectionView.contentOffset.x += 50

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: nil)

    print(imageCollectionView.contentOffset.x)

}
```